# Why the left margin in is bigger than the one set by using the "geometry" package?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, margins

I am working to the design of a book cover to be used on a user manual, and despite having set the right and left margins to 1cm by use of the `geometry` package, the left margin is approximately 4mm larger than required. The code I run is the following one:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
% Preamble

% Language settings
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

% Layout settings
\usepackage[a4paper, %
xetex, %
asymmetric, %
left=1.0cm, %
right=1.0cm, %
top=1.2cm, %
bottom=2cm, %
includefoot,centering]{geometry}  % cover page layout
\usepackage{fontspec}   % ttf font inclusion
\setmainfont{Arial}     % choice of main font

% Special commands
\newcommand{\subtitle}{Istruzioni originali} % Sottotitolo
\newcommand{\machineclass}{Partizionatrice scenica} % Classe di macchine
\newcommand{\machinename}{PEA} % Nome macchina
\newcommand{\ATEXclass}{Non-zona} % Classe ATEX
\newcommand{\hstep}{\hspace*{0.5cm}}

% Last page identifier package
\usepackage[]{pageslts}   % Needed for current page to total number of   pages calculation
                          % in headers and footers

% Numbering of \subsubsection and appearance in TOC
\addtocounter{secnumdepth}{1}  % section numbering (add 1 to standard secnumdepth)
\addtocounter{tocdepth}{1}     % TOC numbering (add 1 to standard tocnumdepth)

% Debug settings
\usepackage{checkend}

% General packages
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{CIMBRIA_green}{rgb}{0,0.254901961,0.211764706}
\definecolor{CIMBRIA_sort}{rgb}{0,0.392156863,0.654901961}
\definecolor{CIMBRIA_red}{rgb}{0.909803922,0.266666667,0.152941176}
\usepackage[allbordercolors={1 1 1}]{hyperref}
\usepackage[code=Code39,H=0.8cm]{makebarcode}
\usepackage{siunitx}

% Preamble commands
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex   % Index creation
\title{\machinename}  % Title 

% Title 
\newcommand*{\titleSEA}{\begingroup% Title page CIMBRIA
  \raggedright
  \colorbox{CIMBRIA_green}{
    \parbox[t]{1.0\textwidth}{
     \raggedright
      {\textcolor{CIMBRIA_red}{CIMBRIA.COM | MI0003-IT}}\\[3\baselineskip]
      {\textcolor{CIMBRIA_red}{\MakeUppercase{\subtitle}}}\\[0.5\baselineskip]
      {\Huge\bfseries\textcolor{CIMBRIA_red}{\MakeUppercase{\machineclass}}}\\[3.0\baselineskip]
      {\Large\bfseries\textcolor{CIMBRIA_sort}{\MakeUppercase{\machinename}}}\\[0.5\baselineskip]
      {\textcolor{CIMBRIA_sort}{\MakeUppercase{\ATEXclass}}}
      \par
    }
  }
  \vfill
\endgroup}

% Body of the document
\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\thispagestyle{empty} % Remove page numbering on this page
\clearpage
\titleSEA\
\clearpage
Copyright\copyright\ 2016 Cimbria S.r.l.
\bigskip
\bigskip

\textbf{Istruzioni originali}
\bigskip

Numero identificativo: MI0004-IT

Data rilascio: 2016-02-02
\bigskip

Queste istruzioni sono in Italiano.

\barcode{MI0004-IT-02-2016}

\backmatter

\end{document}
```

Shown below the result I got edited with gimp to show clearly what I mean: as you can see, also the text inside the green box starts with an horizontal offset of nearly 6pt.
[image: Cover page with larger left margin]

Summing up, my question is simple: why I get a larger left margin and a horizontal offset on the text inside the green box?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TeX gives clear warnings in the log that your title box did not fit in the line.

You had added word spaces from missing `%` at the end of the lines and not accounted for the `\fboxsep` padding around `\colorbox`.

Having removed the colorbox padding you might want to add some vertical padding at least but your left margin is now flush left:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
% Preamble

% Language settings
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

% Layout settings
\usepackage[a4paper, %
xetex, %
asymmetric, %
left=1.0cm, %
right=1.0cm, %
top=1.2cm, %
bottom=2cm, %
includefoot,centering]{geometry}  % cover page layout
\usepackage{fontspec}   % ttf font inclusion
\setmainfont{Arial}     % choice of main font

% Special commands
\newcommand{\subtitle}{Istruzioni originali} % Sottotitolo
\newcommand{\machineclass}{Partizionatrice scenica} % Classe di macchine
\newcommand{\machinename}{PEA} % Nome macchina
\newcommand{\ATEXclass}{Non-zona} % Classe ATEX
\newcommand{\hstep}{\hspace*{0.5cm}}

% Last page identifier package
\usepackage[]{pageslts}   % Needed for current page to total number of   pages calculation
                          % in headers and footers

% Numbering of \subsubsection and appearance in TOC
\addtocounter{secnumdepth}{1}  % section numbering (add 1 to standard secnumdepth)
\addtocounter{tocdepth}{1}     % TOC numbering (add 1 to standard tocnumdepth)

% Debug settings
\usepackage{checkend}

% General packages
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{CIMBRIA_green}{rgb}{0,0.254901961,0.211764706}
\definecolor{CIMBRIA_sort}{rgb}{0,0.392156863,0.654901961}
\definecolor{CIMBRIA_red}{rgb}{0.909803922,0.266666667,0.152941176}
\usepackage[allbordercolors={1 1 1}]{hyperref}
\usepackage[code=Code39,H=0.8cm]{makebarcode}
\usepackage{siunitx}

% Preamble commands
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex   % Index creation
\title{\machinename}  % Title 

% Title 
\newcommand*{\titleSEA}{\begingroup% Title page CIMBRIA
  \raggedright
  \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
  \colorbox{CIMBRIA_green}{%%%%%
    \parbox[t]{1.0\textwidth}{%%%%%(not as bad as the one above
     \raggedright
      {\textcolor{CIMBRIA_red}{CIMBRIA.COM | MI0003-IT}}\\[3\baselineskip]
      {\textcolor{CIMBRIA_red}{\MakeUppercase{\subtitle}}}\\[0.5\baselineskip]
      {\Huge\bfseries\textcolor{CIMBRIA_red}{\MakeUppercase{\machineclass}}}\\[3.0\baselineskip]
      {\Large\bfseries\textcolor{CIMBRIA_sort}{\MakeUppercase{\machinename}}}\\[0.5\baselineskip]
      {\textcolor{CIMBRIA_sort}{\MakeUppercase{\ATEXclass}}}%%%%
      \par
    }%%%%%
  }%%%
  \vfill
\endgroup}

% Body of the document
\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\thispagestyle{empty} % Remove page numbering on this page
\clearpage
\titleSEA
\clearpage
Copyright\copyright\ 2016 Cimbria S.r.l.
\bigskip
\bigskip

\textbf{Istruzioni originali}
\bigskip

Numero identificativo: MI0004-IT



Data rilascio: 2016-02-02
\bigskip

Queste istruzioni sono in Italiano.

\barcode{MI0004-IT-02-2016}

\backmatter

\end{document}
```

Comment: @DavidCarlise. Thank you very much: your suggestion helped me a lot. I must also add that, apart from trying your suggestion, I removed also a vestigial (however harmless) `centering` parameter in `geometry`.

Comment: @DavidCarlise. After a few try of your suggestion I decided to change my original `parbox` statement in the following one `\parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth - 2\fboxsep\relax}`, in order to have the correct box length for every choice of `\fboxsep`. Also, in order to make the green box fill the space up to the upper margin of 1.2cm (`top=1.2cm` in the `geometry` package),  changed the `t` position parameter to `b`. Regarding this latter choice I haven't seen any warning in the log file, but I'd like to know your opinion on this way of doing things. Thanks in advance